# script to copy same file to a folder continuously in linux

Tags: linux, file-copy

I want a script to copy the same file from source folder to target folder by incrementing the filename (ex. file1, file2, file3, file4,....). This would be for some performance testing.

I've got this code so far, but how best can it be achieved?

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in 1 2
do cp /tmp/ABC*/folder1/ABC*$i
done
```

Comment: #!/bin/sh
for i in 1 2
do
  cp /tmp/ABC* /mnt/share/reception/13_calling_cards_data/ABC*$i
done

Comment: Do you want the same source file copied to the same target or a different target each time?. It's not clear from your question whether you want (A→A) repeated _n_ times, or (A→Aⁿ) for increasing values of _n_.

Comment: Richard, is [that comment of yours](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686217/script-to-copy-same-file-to-a-folder-continuously-in-linux#comment1297025_686217) your own suggestion as a starting point, or a solution that you're now using?

Comment: hi @roaima I want to copy the same file from source folder to target folder but just by incrementing the filename (ex. file1, file2, file3, file4 ....) continuously.

Comment: you can't use a wild card (as a wild card) in the target name. Other than that, the approach works. Put your file name in a variable, put your target directory in a variable, and you'll be all set :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a forever-repeating loop

```
#!/bin/sh
n=1
while true
do
    cp /tmp/ABCfile "/mnt/share/reception/13_calling_cards_data/ABCfile.$n"
    n=$(( n+1 ))
done
```

Comment: Thanks @roaima :)